# Why does sem (GNU parallel) behave differently with single quotes and double quotes?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I can't understand the following behavior of `sem` from GNU Parallel.
When I use single quotes, it seems to work well:

```
sem -j1 'echo $(date);sleep 5;echo $(date)'
sem --wait
```

gives

```
Sat Apr 23 15:46:50 EDT 2016
Sat Apr 23 15:46:55 EDT 2016
```

However, when I use double quotes.

```
sem -j1 "echo $(date);sleep 5;echo $(date)"
sem --wait
```

the result is

```
Sat Apr 23 15:46:08 EDT 2016
Sat Apr 23 15:46:08 EDT 2016
```

where it seems that the `sleep 5` is totally ignored.

Could anyone explain why this happens? Is it caused by GNU parallel or bash?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `sem` or GNU parallel, but everything to do with the shell.

When you use double-quotes for strings, the shell expands all environment variable references *at once*. If you use single-quoted strings the shell doesn't do that variable expansion.